# preg_replace custom ranges

Tags: php, preg-replace

The user input is stored in the variable $input.

so i want to use preg replace to swap the letters from the user input that will range from a-z, with my own custom alphabet.

My code i am trying, which doesnt work is below:

```
preg_replace('/([a-z])/', "y,p,l,t,a,v,k,r,e,z,g,m,s,h,u,b,x,n,c,d,i,j,f,q,o,w", $input)
```

This code however doesnt work.

If anyone has any suggestions on how i can get this working then that would be great. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't jump for `preg`, when `str` is enough:

```
$regular = range('a', 'z');
$custom = explode(',', "y,p,l,t,a,v,k,r,e,z,g,m,s,h,u,b,x,n,c,d,i,j,f,q,o,w");
$output = str_replace($regular, $custom, $input);
```

Comment: +1 however use `str_ireplace` if OP wants to replace upper case characters as well with custom set.

Comment: `yahoo` gets translated to `oonii` where it should be `oyruu`.

Answer (score 3):

Using [`str_replace`](http://php.net/str_replace) makes a lot more sense in this case:

```
str_replace(
    range("a", "z"), // Creates an array with all lowercase letters
    explode(",", "y,p,l,t,a,v,k,r,e,z,g,m,s,h,u,b,x,n,c,d,i,j,f,q,o,w"),
    $input
);
```

Answer (score 3):

You could instead use [`strtr()`](http://php.net/strtr), this resolves the problem of replacing already replaced values.

```
echo strtr($input, 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz', 'ypltavkrezgmshubxncdijfqow');
```

With `$input` as `yahoo` the output is `oyruu`, as expected.

Answer (score 1):

A potential problem with the solutions given is that multiple replacements *could* occur for each character. eg. 'a' gets replaced by 'y', and in the same statement 'y' gets replaced by 'o'. So, in the examples given above, 'aaa' becomes 'ooo', not 'yyy' that might be expected. And 'yyy' becomes 'ooo' as well. The resulting string is essentially garbage. You'd never be able to convert it back, if that was a requirement.

You could get around this using two replacements.

On the first replacement you replace the `$regular` chars with an intermediate set of character sequences that don't exist in `$input`. eg. 'a' to '[[[a]]]', 'b' to '[[[b]]]', etc.

Then replace the intermediate character sequences with your `$custom` set of chars. eg. '[[[a]]]' to 'y', '[[[b]]]' to 'p', etc.

Like so...

```
$regular = range('a', 'z');
$custom = explode(',', 'y,p,l,t,a,v,k,r,e,z,g,m,s,h,u,b,x,n,c,d,i,j,f,q,o,w');

// Create an intermediate set of char (sequences) that don't exist anywhere else in the $input
// eg. '[[[a]]]', '[[[b]]]', ...
$intermediate = $regular;
array_walk($intermediate,create_function('&$value','$value="[[[$value]]]";'));

// Replace the $regular chars with the $intermediate set
$output = str_replace($regular, $intermediate, $input);

// Replace the $intermediate chars with our custom set
$output = str_replace($intermediate, $custom, $output);
```

**EDIT:**

Leaving this solution for reference, but @salathe's solution to use `strtr()` is *much* better!